# Gauss Original Paper

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, references, least-squares, history

I am looking for Gauss's 1809 paper in which he introduced least squares regression, MLE and the gaussian distribution. I cannot find it online. Can someone tell me where I may find it?

Answer (score 3):

According to author of several books on history of statistics, [Stephen M. Stigler (1981)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176345451), the method of least squares was first described by Carl Friedrich Gauss in 1809 in his  *Theoria Modus Corporum Coelestium* [[*Theory of the Motion of Heavenly Bodies*](https://archive.org/details/theoryofmotionof00gausuoft/)] book. [In the same work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#History) Gauss proposed a form of normal distribution that is similar to what we use today. It seems to be the book you are referring to.